# How to store string variables in php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session-variables

```
$matrix=array($_SESSION['review_buffer_name'],$_SESSION['review_buffer_mail'],$_SESSION['review_buffer_comment']);
```

The above line of code is inside WHILE loop So that it stores more than one record of array.Is it correct way to store records?. And how can we access each record and value of matrix?

$matrix should store multiple row of arrays... The problem is when i'm accessing $matrix[2] then it is giving second value of array... instead of second record of array

Comment: Share your while loop? exactly what do you want to do? Describe the using of $matrix array.

Comment: $matrix should store multiple row of arrays... The problem is when i'm accessing $matrix[2] then it is giving second value of array... instead of second record of array

Comment: It because your `$matrix` is a usual list and it doesn't seems that you are appending anything to your result collection bec. you always rewriting `$matrix` variable if that particular statement is in your `while`. Try to use `$matrix[] = [ ... ];` and see what changes or share more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try it:**

```
//Before while loop declare the array variable
$matrix = array();

While(your condition){
    $matrix[] = array(
           $_SESSION['review_buffer_name'],
           $_SESSION['review_buffer_mail'],
           $_SESSION['review_buffer_comment']
   );
}

//To access array:

print_r($matrix[0]); //print_r whole first row. (array start from 0)
echo $matrix[0][0]; //echo single data that first row's first data
```

> **Or you can set index as name like:**

```
//Before while loop declare the array variable
$matrix = array();

While(your condition){
    $matrix[] = array(
           'review_buffer_name'=>$_SESSION['review_buffer_name'],
           'review_buffer_mail'=>$_SESSION['review_buffer_mail'],
           'review_buffer_comment'=>$_SESSION['review_buffer_comment']
    );
    }

//Then access array:

print_r($matrix[0]); //print_r whole first row. (array start from 0)
echo $matrix[0]['review_buffer_name']; // first row's first data
```